# activeadmin: keeps loading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I ve got model `Comment` trying to administer this model with activeadmin:

```
rails g active_admin:resource Comment
```

Active admin created file: `app\admin\comments.rb` with:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment, :as => 'AllComments' do
  menu :parent => "Campaigns", :priority => 55

end
```

From `rake:routes`:

```
                        admin_all_comments GET    /admin/all_comments(.:format)                                                      admin/all_comments#index
                                           POST   /admin/all_comments(.:format)                                                      admin/all_comments#create
                     new_admin_all_comment GET    /admin/all_comments/new(.:format)                                                  admin/all_comments#new
                    edit_admin_all_comment GET    /admin/all_comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                             admin/all_comments#edit
                         admin_all_comment GET    /admin/all_comments/:id(.:format)                                                  admin/all_comments#show
                                           PUT    /admin/all_comments/:id(.:format)                                                  admin/all_comments#update
                                           DELETE /admin/all_comments/:id(.:format)                                                  admin/all_comments#destroy
                            admin_comments GET    /admin/comments(.:format)                                                                      admin/comments#index
```

Issue: while accessing `admin\all_comments` I got that comments are loading for ages.

Note:

1. There are only 24 records in the `comment` model
2. Comment model is a polymorphic association as described by Ryan Bates (http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)
3. I am using `kaminari` settings {`paginates_per 10`} on `comment` model, however that should not affect activeadmin at all, from my perspective, of course
4. There is no output from the console, and it def there is no error, so that's why it keeps loading the page

Any help regarding this question would be appreciated

My Stack:
`ruby-1.9.3-p125`, `rails-3.2.8`, `WEBrick 1.3.1`, `mac os lion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here was the solution, I added `filter: commentable` in `Comments.rb` and I worked fine